# IntelliJ IDEA does not scan maven centralized repository for artifacts

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ide, pom.xml

In eclipse the dependency artifacts can be searched from the centralized repository with maven plugin and added to the pom.xml file.  But in IntelliJ IDEA the [dependency search](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-maven-dependencies.html) work only in local repository.  If the searched artifact is not in local repository,  the result would be empty.
Is there a way to search for artifacts from central repository and add it to pom.xml in IntelliJ ?

Comment: Have you Maven Indexed repository configured (Configuration -> Maven -> Repositories). Do you have a list of repository which are shown as indexed?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, Settings | Maven | Repositories, click on the repository and then click on Update, it will get indexed.

Comment: I have updated the maven Repositories : Settings -> Maven -> Repositories. In "Indexed Maven Repositories" list the URL "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" and my local repository are listed. I updated by clicking "Update" button.  But still dependency search works only in local repository.  My maven version is 2.2.1.

Comment: Strange, I would try support, of issue tracker.

Comment: I updated the maven version 3.1.1. The issue got resolved. Thanks.